# Why can I change a constant object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constants

I know that ES6 is not standardized yet, but a [lot of browsers currently support](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/) `const` keyword in JS.

In spec, it is written that:

> The value of a constant cannot change through re-assignment, and a
> constant cannot be re-declared. Because of this, although it is
> possible to declare a constant without initializing it, it would be
> useless to do so.

and when I do something like this:

```
const xxx = 6;
xxx = 999;
xxx++;
const yyy = [];
yyy = 'string';
yyy = [15, 'a'];
```

I see that everything is ok: `xxx` is still `6` and `yyy` is `[]`.

But if I do `yyy.push(6); yyy.push(1);` , my constant array has been changed. Right now it is `[6, 1]` and by the way I still can not change it with `yyy = 1;`.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something? I tried it in the latest chrome and FF29

Comment: Can you just create a class, declare the variable and assign its value inside the class. Then, create a GETTER for that variable; and do not implement a setter. It should implement a constant...

Comment: @Andrew thanks, but I am not asking how can I do this. I am curious why const keyword behaves this way.

Answer (score 309, accepted):

MDN [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) states:

> ...constant cannot change through re-assignment
> ...constant cannot be re-declared

When you're adding to an array or object you're not re-assigning or re-declaring the constant; it's already declared and assigned. You're just adding to the list of elements or properties to which the constant points.

So this works fine:

```
const x = {};

x.foo = 'bar';

console.log(x); // {foo : 'bar'}

x.foo = 'bar2';

console.log(x); // {foo : 'bar2'}
```

and this:

```
const y = [];

y.push('foo');

console.log(y); // ['foo']

y.unshift("foo2");

console.log(y); // ['foo2', 'foo']

y.pop();

console.log(y); // ['foo2']
```

but neither of these:

```
const x = {};
x = {foo: 'bar'}; // error - re-assigning

const y = ['foo'];
const y = ['bar']; // error - re-declaring

const foo = 'bar'; 
foo = 'bar2';       // error - can not re-assign
var foo = 'bar3';   // error - already declared
function foo() {};  // error - already declared
```

Comment: so you mean that this is not a bug, but it should work this way? Because I thought that idea of the constant is that it can not be changed. Basically a programmer has trust that no matter what will happen, nothing can change the value inside of my constant.

Comment: I think it's not so easy, in this case the value of the constant is an array of specific elements. Changing anything means that you change the *value*.

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to work this way, you're not re-assigning the constant, it's still the same reference, you're just adding to the array the constant references, and arrays and objects are like "lists", modifying them does not change the reference or re-declare the constant.

Comment: @SalvadorDali: *constant* and *read-only* are two different things. Your variable is *constant*, but the array it's pointing to isn't *read-only*

Comment: So basically the variable is a pointer, and as `const` you cannot change the memory address it is referencing or pointing to, but you're free to change the value that memory address is holding?

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari - The above is not incorrect. What code do you think works in a way that contradicts the above? Note that unless you're doing `const x = ____;` and the later doing `x = ____`, the code you're using does not contradict the above.

Answer (score 88):

This happens because your constant is actually storing a *reference* to the array. When you join something into your array you are not modifying your constant value, but the array it points to. The same would happen if you assigned an object to a constant and tried to modify any property of it.

If you want to freeze an array or object so it can't be modified, you can use the [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) method, which is already part of ECMAScript 5.

```
const x = Object.freeze(['a'])
x.push('b')
console.log(x) // ["a"]
```

Comment: By that same logic, a constant `five` set to 5 doesn't actually have a value of 5, it is just a reference to the number 5. So if I do `five++` I'm not changing the constant, just the number it points to.

Comment: @Anthony the reference thing only works for arrays and objects, not primitive values

Comment: @Anthony In your example, you're changing the number that the variable `five` points to (the variable `five` used to be a label for the number 5, now it's pointing to a different number: 6). In the example in the question (and this answer), `x` always points to the same list; if `x` is const you cannot make it point to a different list. The only difference is that the same list can grow or shrink; this is something only possible for arrays and objects and not for primitives.

Answer (score 22):

Came through this article while searching on why I was able to update an Object even after defining it as `const`. So the point here is that it is not the Object directly but the attributes it contains which can be updated.

For example, my Object looks like:

```
const number = {
    id:5,
    name:'Bob'
};
```

The above answers correctly pointed out that it's the Object which is const and not its attribute. Hence, I will be able to update the id or name by doing:

```
number.name = 'John';
```

But, I will not be able to update the Object itself like:

```
number = {
    id:5,
    name:'John'
  };

TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
```

Comment: your example is a practical one and correct descriptions

Answer (score 17):

This is consistent behavior with every programming language I can think of.

Consider C - arrays are just glorified pointers. A constant array only means that the value of the pointer will not change - but in fact the data contained at that address is free to.

In javascript, you are allowed to call methods of constant objects (of course - otherwise constant objects would not serve much purpose!) These methods might have the side effect of modifying the object. Since arrays in javascript are objects, this behavior applies to them as well.

All you are assured of is that the constant will always point to the same object. The properties of the object itself are free to change.

Comment: Swift is an example of a language which does not work like this. `let someArray = ["one"]; someArray.append("two")` fails to compile with `error: cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'someArray' is a 'let' constant` and `note: change 'let' to 'var' to make it mutable`.

Comment: Explaining why I'm downvoting. There's an obvious reason why this is being asked; because it's contrary to what programmers are used to. Constants in C/C++ are typically defined by an immutable macro, in PHP by a specific `define()` function. When programmers say "constant", they typically mean "something that will not change", nevermind the mathetmatics under the hood. That's why ONLY IN JAVASCRIPT people are consistently confused by this bizarre choice of keyword use; because it's a bad one. The answer here isn't technically incorrect per se, it's just also not very useful.

Answer (score 11):

The keyword const is a little misleading.

It does not define a constant value. It defines a constant reference to a value.

Because of this you can NOT:

- Reassign a constant value
- Reassign a constant array
- Reassign a constant object

But you CAN:

- Change a constant array
- Change a constant object

Comment: thank you on this. It clarifies how const works in JS that damn cumbersome compared to other langs especially statically typed language.

Comment: Upvoting for pointing out that the keyword is misleading.

It is.

Answer (score 8):

I think this would give you more clarity on the issue : https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0 .

Basically it boils down to the `const` always pointing to the same address in memory. You can change the value stored in that address but cannot change the address the `const` is pointing too.

The definition of `const` you mentioned will hold true when the `const` is pointing to an address that holds a primitive value . This is because you cannot assign a value to this `const` without changing its address (because this is how assigning primitive values work) and changing the address of a `const` is not allowed.

Where as if the `const` is pointing to non-primitive value , it is possible to edit the value of the address.

Comment: here is another beginner-friendly explanation of how primitive types and objects are saved in memory and their subsequently different behaviour (from 2017 so slightly dated, but a pretty good introduction to the topic):  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ooYYRLdg_g

Answer (score 4):

> The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned. For instance, in the case where the content is an object, this means the object's contents (e.g., its parameters) can be altered.

In addition, an also important note:

> Global constants do not become properties of the window object ...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Answer (score 1):

The value of a const can't be changed through reassignment, and it       can't be redeclared.

```
const testData = { name:"Sandeep",lastName:"Mukherjee",company:"XYZ"}
```

**First case**

```
testData = {name:"hello"}
console.log(testData);//throws an Error:Assignment to constant variable
Here we are reassigning testData again
```

**Second case**

```
const testData = {name:"Sandeep",lastName:"Mukherjee",company:"ABC"}
console.log(testData); //throws an Error: Identifier 'testData' has already been declared
Here we are redeclaring testData again
```

When a variable is declared using const it means it points to some memory location the
behaviour of const is we can manipulate the value stored in that memory location but not
the memory location,when we reassign/redeclare the const variable it
does not allow to change the memory location

*We can change the value of a specific key*

```
testData.company = "Google"
 console.log(testData);
 //{ name: 'Sandeep', lastName: 'Mukherjee', company: 'Google' }
```

*We can add any new key value pair to it*

```
 testData.homeTown = "NewYork"
 console.log(testData)
 //{name: 'Sandeep',lastName:'Mukherjee',company:'Google',homeTown: 'NewYork'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in const you can change the values of an object, so the object does not actually store the assignment data but instead, it points to it.
so there is a difference between primitives and objects in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

const variable stores the address (memory address such as 0xFF2DFC) that is constant.

The constant is NOT the content at the memory.

***constant is memory address ONLY***

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

`const MY_OBJECT = {'key': 'value'};`

// Attempting to overwrite the object throws an error
// Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
`MY_OBJECT = {'OTHER_KEY': 'value'};`

// However, object keys are not protected,
// so the following statement is executed without problem
`MY_OBJECT.key = 'otherValue';`
// Use Object.freeze() to make object immutable

// The same applies to arrays
`const MY_ARRAY = [];`
// It's possible to push items into the array
`MY_ARRAY.push('A');` // ["A"]
// However, assigning a new array to the variable throws an error
// Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
`MY_ARRAY = ['B'];`

Answer (score 0):

In your constant is saved not the object, but link to the object.

You can't change this link, because it is constant.
But object you can change.

Answer (score 0):

First of all *const* declared variables cannot be **redeclared or reassigned**.

`const foo = 5;` //initializing to a primitive data type , Assigned to the **value**

`const bar = [1,2,3];` //initializing to an object(array,object,function,...) , Assigned to the **reference of the object**

If you are trying to reassign a variable with **const** you will get **Uncaught TypeError:Assignment to constant variable**.

You can't do either of this!

```
const five=5; // initialized to a value
five=6;       // trying to reassign

const obj={};
obj = {foo:"foo",bar:"bar"}; //trying to reassign
```

But you can modify object like this

```
const obj ={};
obj.foo="foo";
obj.bar="bar";
console.log(obj); //{foo:"bar,bar:"bar"}

const arr=[];
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;
arr[3] = 4;
console.log(arr); //[1,2,undefined,4]
```

> Note: We're not changing the reference, just changing the data that the reference points to.

Feel free to comment if any doubts...