# Why does a const constant assign an object, and a constant can modify the value of the object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1KjJ.png)

---

Why myVariable can be modified?

---

```
const obj = {
    a: 'a'
}
const myVariable = obj;

try{
    myVariable = { a: 'c' } //The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value
}catch(e){
    console.log(e);
}

myVariable.a = 'b';

console.log(myVariable); //{a: "b"}
```

Comment: because it's teh same object

Comment: object pointed by both const is the same.Objects are copied by reference instead of by value

Comment: `const` just ensures that the variable cannot be reassigned. Changing a property of an object does not reassign the value of the variable (it is the same reference) so what you have indicated will work. If you wanted to make sure no more properties are added/modified you could explore [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

Comment: if you want, you can `Object.freeze(obj)` - then it's frozen - not deeply though

Comment: You are mixing/confusing (im)mutable **bindings** (variables) with (im)mutable **values**. They are two different things. `const` makes the binding immutable, not the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your constant is actually storing a reference to the object. When you're adding to object you're not re-assigning or re-declaring the constant,you're just adding to the "list" that the constant points to.Refer more here : [Why can I change value of a constant in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23436437/why-can-i-change-value-of-a-constant-in-javascript)

Comment: Looks like this should simply be closed as duplicate then.