# Understanding Arrowfunctions with additional list added to function

Tags: reactjs

I am doing a tutorial, and there is some code there that i am not sure i understand:

```
const Numbers = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="card text-center innline">
            { Numbers.list.map((number, i) => 
                <span key={i}>{number}</span> 
            )}
        </div>
    );
};
Numbers.list = _.range(1,10);
```

I understand correctly that a constant can not be modified after creation, but what is the Number.list doing on the last line of the code. Is it adding a list to the Numbers function, or are those to separate objects?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can I change value of a constant in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23436437/why-can-i-change-value-of-a-constant-in-javascript)

Comment: JJJ i am not asking about why i cant change a constant, i am asking what happens in the code. Van answered it for me

Comment: The duplicate explains the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

`const` keyword will create an immutable binding not an immutable variable, i.e. if you assign a new property it won't return an error but if you try to assign a new value to the variable like `Numbers = {}` then it will return an error.

So it is possible to assign a property like above code row `Numbers.list = _.range(1,10);`.

And in the code above, running `Numbers()` to execute the function after assigning `Numbers.list` will be successful and correctly returning a jsx container with 10 span elements. 
However, if you run `Numbers()` without assigning the `list` property beforehand, it'll throw an error as `Numbers.list` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript constants can't be reassigned, but the value inside it can be edited, especially if those are objects.

The row:

```
Numbers.list = _.range(1,10);
```

doesn't reassign Numbers, but it's assigning a value to `Numbers.list`.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript functions are objects and act as such. `Numbers.list = ...` adds `list` property to `Numbers`. `Numbers` is a function that has `Numbers.list` array property, which is an object, too.

`const Numbers = ...` assigns `Numbers` with function (object) *reference* and prevents a *variable* from being reassigned. It doesn't prevent an object from modifications, unless an object has been frozen with `Object.freeze`.