# How to fetch array from an array?

Tags: javascript

How can i fetch array  which is inside of an array at different indexes.

Here my const variable  X = [[{..}],[{..}]] contain values at different arrays inside of array X

```
[[{0:a}] , [{0:b}] , [{0:c}]]
```

```
const x = [[{0:a}] , [{0:b}] , [{0:c}]]
let y = null;
let index = 1;
y = x[index] //it does not get array from x first index array...
```

```
y = x[index]
//output [{…}]0: {0: -1}length: 1__proto__: Array(0)
I want to get this as output => [{0:b}]
```

I have `const index = 1;`
How can I get index 1 array into `const z = null` initially `const z` is initialized as nul

Comment: Please update your post, the pseudocode you're showing has an object at `X[1][0]`, not an array. Also, the code you show says the error is on the `console.log`, but then your text says it's on the line _after_ that: which one is it? So, getting us to [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask): please don't show pseudocode, actually show [mcve] code instead.

Comment: @Mike I just update the question

Comment: const variable can't be reinitialized 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23436563/13647574

so firstly change your const to var/let

and other part of your question you have to give some proper example

Comment: Please update your post again after clicking and (re)reading how to ask a good question: you've now removed the code that was useful, and updated the code that wasn't to something that still isn't very useful. Just write actual code that folks can run: `const x = [ [{a:1}], [{b:2}] ];`, there, now you have a working representation of `x`, just add more code that shows how you're trying to get to what you're trying to get out of `x`, and then people can comment on how close you are to making that work.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question correctly. You want the the variable `y` to equal `x[index]` right?

I tried your code out and everything seems to be working fine here:

Perhaps the issue is that you are using the `const` variable, try using `let` or `var` like previous replies have emphasized. However, you aren't re-assigning the const variable so not sure how that could be the problem, but I might be mistaken. Regardless, this code below works, so do comment if that doesn't solve your issue. :))

```js
const x = [[{0:"a"}] , [{0:"b"}] , [{0:"c"}]]
let y = null;
let index = 1;
y = x[index];
y = x[index];

console.log(...y);
```

---

The output is:

```
{0: "b"}
```

---

Is this what you want?