javascript params variable force changing somehow even if a const variable
I'm trying to keep the base value of something but will still not keep its value even if its a const and param? I dont know how it does that but heres my code.
function load_descendants(elem,array,mooo)
{
  const origin = mooo
  for (var c=0;c<array[0].length;c++)
  {
    //NOTE WHILE EDITING ON STACK OVERFLOW: the variable "mooo" from each loop some reason gets changed and keeps its value and kind of breaks the rules of javascript somehow
    var mew = origin
    console.log(origin,mew,c)
    if (c!=0) {
      mew.splice(mew.length-2,2) // had to add in because the param mooo wouldnt keep its value since its supposed to do that?
    }
    mew.push("["+0+"]")
    mew.push("["+c+"]")
    var ob = new_child_object(array[0][c][1],array[0][c][2],mew)
    if (ob != false)
    {
      elem.appendChild(ob[0])
      if (array[0][c][0].length != 0) {
        load_descendants(ob[1],array[0][c],ob[2])
      }
    }
  }
}

function loadExplorer()
{
  document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = ""
  Object.entries(GAME).forEach(([k,v]) => {
    var ob = new_object(v[1],v[2],[v[1]])
    document.getElementById("main").appendChild(ob[0])
    load_descendants(ob[1],v,[k])
    update_width()
  })
}

loadExplorer()

I've tried to stop the values from changing but all it does is keep the last values from the for loop and give the same values it changed to the next index loop I even checked every variable if it had the same name and changed the index variables but there isn't any change. Please if you have an answer I would appreciate it.

mew, origin and mooo are all the exact same object since = doesn't create copies. You need to copy the mutable object if you want different versions of it to exist. Also note that const doesn't guarantee that an object can't be mutated; it guarantees that a reference to an object can't be reassigned. Legal: const a = []; a.push(1);. Not legal: const a = []; a = {}.

Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23436437/why-can-i-change-a-constant-object-in-javascript

When an object is assigned to a variable/constant, its value is not actually the object itself but a pointer to the object. So mew = origin doesn't create a copy of the object, it only creates a copy of the pointer to the same object. Manipulating the object doesn't change the pointer, that's why it works on a const. The object itself is not immutable. It's a bit counter-intuitive and difficult of a concept to grasp, but when you get more familiar with JS it will make perfect sense.

@Carcigenicate I mean I'm not getting any errors off of it and the params just change their values since they have to keep it.

@Lennholm can you show it in code? to give me a better understanding

@VictorAvelar Read the answers in the question I linked to, they contain example code

Why would you get errors? The parameter is never reassigns, nor are any of the const variables of yours. You seem to be mixing up objects being mutated and references to objects being reassigned.

I've got like a whole 937 line js file im just figuring it out right now. Like there might not be errors but im just revising with the information i have right now

@AlexanderNenashev I dont know. Its im just trying to see if any of those questions can do the job

@Lennholm also thanks you solved my problem just had to research!

After 5 hours I've got it. I just needed to get a deep copy of the variable. Thanks also. Heres the link if anyone is on this problem also Copy a variable's value into another

Note though, since mew/mooo/origin appear to contain strings, only a shallow copy is necessary. Deep copies (which tend to be more expensive) are only necessary when the inner elements are mutable, and strings are immutable.
